# non responsive section of site with javascript

Tags: javascript, text, responsiveness

I have a section of a site that is not being responsive. The whole site is responsive except for this one text portion.  It is a scrolling text with java.

I have tried a bunch of @media and size restrictions but nothing works.  This is the only part that does not work.

```js
function initQuoteCarousel() {

    var $quotesWrapper = $(".cust-quotes");
    var $quotes = $quotesWrapper.find("blockquote");

    if (!$quotes.length) {
        return;
    }

    var selectNextQuote = function () {
        // keep move first quote in dom to the end to make continous
        var $quote = $quotesWrapper.find("blockquote:first").detach().appendTo($quotesWrapper);

        setTimeout(selectNextQuote, $quote.data("timeout"));
    };

    setTimeout(selectNextQuote, $quotes.filter(":first").data("timeout"));

}

$(function () {
    initQuoteCarousel();
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px/20px Arial,sans-serif;
  color:#222;
}

.cust-quotes {
  width: 640px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
}

.cust-quotes blockquote {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out 0s, transform 0.5s ease-in 0s;
}

/* IE < 10 fallback */
.no-csstransitions .cust-quotes blockquote,
.no-csstransforms .cust-quotes blockquote {
   position:relative;
}

.cust-quotes blockquote:first-child {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-10px) scale(1.1);
}
.cust-quotes blockquote:first-child + blockquote {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: opacity 1.6s ease 0s;
}
.cust-quotes blockquote p{
  font-size:24px;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-style:italic;
  color:#353535;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.cust-quotes blockquote p:before {
   content: '\201C';
}
.cust-quotes blockquote p:after {
   content: '\201D';
}
.cust-quotes blockquote cite {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #898989;
}
.cust-quotes blockquote cite a {
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;
}



.container {
  
max-width:940px;
margin:0 auto;  

}

#testimonials {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:940px;

}
```

```html
  <section id="testimonials">

<div class="cust-quotes">
  <blockquote data-timeout="1800"><p>Thank you Scott! Our house is cool once again.<br> I have you on speed dial! </p><cite>David Creekmore</cite></blockquote>
  <blockquote data-timeout="1800"><p>The heating/ac system got another clean bill of health from Conrad's Climate Control today. Awesome company.</p><cite>Terry Friar</cite></blockquote>
  <blockquote data-timeout="1800"><p>Scott Conrad of Conrad's Climate Control is awesome! Made a service call in the evening and got my gas logs burning so we can enjoy a great - if fake smile emoticon - fire on this cold, cold evening! Great service - highly recommend him!!</p><cite>Marianne Walston</cite></blockquote>
</div>
  </section>
```

Comment: What do you mean by responsive?

Comment: meaning responsive - mobile and tablet view does  not compress size like the rest of the site

Comment: Your cust-quotes class is fixed width.  Maybe you can provide a fiddle to fully demonstrate the issue?